# how to save memory when training LSTM model with different data shape on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I have build a model with lstm cell as below code, and its inputs are data1 and data2, their shape is [None, 5] which means sometime [3, 5], sometime [13, 5], sometime [80, 5] and most more than [50, 5];

when training, I find used memory is increasing continually with training step which means used memory is more when train more batches and finally memory error after train 200 or 300 batches;

Now I know how to avoid this(used memory is continue increasing when training) by delete "@tf.function", but I don't know why and what is the difference between "@tf.function" and no "@tf.function".

```py
import tensorflow as tf
datas1 = [
        [[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3],[3.,1.2,3.,22.1,23.2,]],
        [[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3],[3.,1.2,3.,22.1,23.2,],[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3],[3.,1.2,3.,22.1,23.2,]],
        [[2,3,2,3,2],[3,2,3,2,2,]],
        [[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3],[3.,1.2,3.,22.1,23.2,],[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3]],
        ...
        ]
datas2 = [
        [[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3],[3.,1.2,3.,22.1,23.2,],[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3]],
        [[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3],[3.,1.2,3.,22.1,23.2,],[3.,1.2,3.,22.1,23.2,]],
        [[2,3,2,3,2],[3,2,3,2,2,]],
        [[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3],[3.,1.2,3.,22.1,23.2,],[2.3,3.3,2,4.3,2.3],[3,2,3,2,2,]],
        ...
        ]
labels = [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0], ...]
L = len(labels)
def generator():
    for i in range(L):
        yield datas1[i], datas2[i], labels[i]
trains = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float16))

class ABC(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ABC, self).__init__()
        self.encoder1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([\
                        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
                        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16)])
        self.encoder2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([\
                        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
                        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16)])
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    def call(self, data1, data2):
        en1 = self.encoder1(data1)
        en2 = self.encoder2(data2)
        en12 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([en1, en2])
        return self.dense(en12)
model = ABC()
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

@tf.function
def train_step(data1, data2, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(data1, data2)
        loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

for i in range(5):
    for data1, data2, label in trains.batch(1):
        train_step(data1, data2, label)
```

Comment: Can you post the error traceback?

Comment: it is memory error; and I think it is because of out of memory;  it runs well when trains several batches, and memory error occur when trains 20th batch or 25 batch like this.

Comment: Did you try to reduce batch size ?

Comment: I find that I can only set batch size as 1, or the model can't run and I think this is because each size of sample is different from others  so they can't be stack in a batch;